How to Create a Histogram of Summed Nested Fields in OpenSearch?
I am working with an OpenSearch index where each document represents a dispute and contains a nested array of transactions. My goal is to compute the sum of a specific field in the nested transactions array for each dispute and then create a histogram of these summed values.
Here is an example of my document structure:
{
  "dispute_id": "123",
  "transactions": [
    {
      "transactionMerchant": "MerchantA",
      "transactionAmount": {
        "amountInCents": 1000,
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    },
    {
      "transactionMerchant": "MerchantB",
      "transactionAmount": {
        "amountInCents": 2000,
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    }
  ]
}

What I’ve Tried
I have successfully created a query that computes the sum of transactions.transactionAmount.amountInCents for each dispute:
POST /dispute/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_dispute": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dispute_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_transactions": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "transactions"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "transaction_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "transactions.transactionAmount.amountInCents"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

This query returns the sum for each dispute correctly. However, my goal is to create a histogram of these sums. I attempted to use a histogram aggregation but ran into issues with nested aggregation limitations in OpenSearch.
Failed Attempt
Here is an example of the query I tried to create a histogram:
POST /dispute/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_dispute": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dispute_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_transactions": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "transactions"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "transaction_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "transactions.transactionAmount.amountInCents"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_histogram": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "by_dispute>nested_transactions>transaction_sum.value",
        "interval": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}

This query returns no histogram following:
"sum_histogram": {
      "buckets": []
},

Question
How can I create a histogram of the summed transaction amounts for each dispute in OpenSearch? Is there a way to achieve this directly in OpenSearch? Any examples or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Can you share an example output for your example data?

    POST /dispute/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_dispute": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dispute_id",
        "size": 10000  // Adjust size as needed
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_transactions": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "transactions"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "transaction_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "transactions.transactionAmount.amountInCents"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "dispute_sum_bucket": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "sum": "nested_transactions>transaction_sum"
            },
            "script": "params.sum"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_histogram": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "by_dispute>dispute_sum_bucket",
        "interval": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
